# Send free sms with java

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, java

In my company we need to send some alerts via SMS gateway, I have used the Nexmo API with java. It works perfect, however our company can't buy the service, so I was thinking; is there any free SMS gateway?

Comment: If the cost per message is the problem, and you're doing a high volume, contact Nexmo to see what can be done (*disclaimer: I work with Nexmo*). Or, if these alerts are for your users, perhaps they could sign up (if they want that feature) and pass their API credentials to you.

Comment: @TimLytle could you give me support?

Comment: @fers Add a ticket here: https://nexmo.zendesk.com/ and I'll make sure you get a response.

Answer (score 0):

There are the free providers that you have found which may limit you to a certain number of messages or impose other restrictions. However many providers support an [email gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) that you might be able to use to send messages. For example if you have a cell number and know the provider (for this example Verizon Wireless) then you can send an email to `number@vtext.com` and it will be sent to the cell as a SMS message. This might be an alternative for you to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The below program is used to send sms using site2sms gateway

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class SendSMS
{
static String SMSApi = "https://site2sms.p.mashape.com/index.php?uid=9095393259&pwd=554182&phone=9751931673&msg=hai";
static String head = "aVi7utR6ZUkGLFkGRwXxd4wLsXz7c1QQ";
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String url = SMSApi;
        String smsApiResponse = sendMySMS(url);
        System.out.println(smsApiResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String sendMySMS(String url)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        URL hp = new URL(url);
        System.out.println(url);
        URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
        hpCon.setRequestProperty("X-Mashape-Authorization", head);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hpCon.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            output.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

}